# JMeter load test async api

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, google-cloud-pubsub

I make a post call to an api, and don't need to log the response (post to google cloud pubsub), but after that i need to measure time it takes for the data to be processed and appear in another GET request (need to keep hitting it unless the response changes).

I also need to measure the performance under load. I tried JMeter but could not figure out a way to get what I wanted. Is there a way to do this in Jmeter? or some other tool that will let me do what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can put your "another GET request" under a [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) so JMeter will keep sending this request unless it will match some defined condition
2. You can put the whole sequence of requests under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) - this way JMeter will measure end-to-end duration of the whole scenario